# mysql join, retrieving data from other tables in a select

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a classic example of table 1 products (productID, name, description, productCategoryID) and table 2 categories (categoryID, name), all i want is to use a select statement to get the product table output but with the product category name instead of ID in the result set, i know this must be very simple but i googled and looked all over similar questions and couldn't understand how the join would work in my case
thank you

Comment: Show us [what you've tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Check [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) is a visual explanation of SQL Joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally we'd see some code of your own... However...

```
SELECT products.productID, 
       products.name as ProductName, 
       products.description, 
       categories.name as CategoryName
FROM Products
INNER JOIN categories 
ON categories.categoryID = Products.productCategoryID
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `JOIN` between the two tables:

```
select p.productId
   p.name as ProductName, 
   p.description,
   c.name CategoryName
from products p
inner join categories c
  on p.productCategoryId = c.categoryId
```

If you need help learning joins, here is a [great visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

I used an `INNER JOIN` between the two tables.  This will return all rows that are matched between the two tables. If you want to return all `products` regardless of whether there is a matching row in the `category` table, then you will want to use a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Snap! And good explanation ;-)

Comment: thank you bluefeet and @PGallagher, this is what i wanted

Comment: there are indeed some products without a categoryId set in the record,   so i used LEFT JOIN, thanks alot